# Node addon using libuv and uv_async_send -- node process doesn't exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, libuv

I have a requirement to invoke a Javascript function from a node addon. The addon will have a background thread that runs continuously, so it's not quite the classic async worker requirement using `async_queue_work`. I think uv_async_send is more appropriate in this scenario. I want to place a function on the node event loop to be executed as soon as node is free. This function should run in the main node thread.

To get started I have a very simple addon and I'm experimenting with `uv_queue_work` vs `uv_async_send`. I can get both to work but in the case of `uv_async_send`, the node process never exits.

**node-uv.cc**

```
#include <node.h>
#include <uv.h>

using namespace v8;

static void Runner(uv_work_t *req)
{
    printf("Async work running!\n");
}

static void RunDone(uv_work_t *req, int status)
{
    delete req;
    printf("Async work done!\n");
}

static void Runner2(uv_async_t* handle) {
    printf("Got async send!\n");
}

void Start(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
    printf("In run async\n");

    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    uv_work_t *req = (uv_work_t*)malloc(sizeof(uv_work_t));

    /// Example using uv_queue_work (working fine)
    printf("Queue work\n");
    uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), req, &Runner, &RunDone);

    uv_async_t *handle = (uv_async_t*)malloc(sizeof(uv_async_t));
    uv_async_init(uv_default_loop(), handle, &Runner2);

    /// Example using uv_async_send (node does not terminate)
    printf("Async send\n");
    uv_async_send(handle);
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
{
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "start", Start);
}

NODE_MODULE(node_uv, Init)
```

**output**

```
$ node test
calling addon
In run async
Queue work
Async send
Async work running!
called addon
Got async send!
Async work done!
```

(process doesn't quit at this point)

The full example project is here: https://github.com/jugglingcats/node-uv

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I didn't call `uv_close`!! Had to be something simple.

**fixed up callback method**

```
static void Runner2(uv_async_t* handle) {
    printf("Got async send! %d\n", n++);
    uv_close((uv_handle_t *)handle, NULL);
}
```

Relevant docs: https://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/threads.html

Fixed github project: https://github.com/jugglingcats/node-uv/tree/working